# How to get the parent(s) of a PID in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Haskell provides

```
-- getProcessID calls getppid to obtain the ProcessID for the parent of the current process.
getParentProcessID :: IO ProcessID
```

but given an external pid, is there an idiomatic way to obtain the parent(s) of this `pid`, perhaps returning a list of them?

Comment: you could use one of the answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line and from Haskell run a process to execute it - not elegant but it should work

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you know how to do this in any other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. I'm basing my answer on Michael Sloan's custom xmonad setup (which you can find [here](https://github.com/mgsloan/mgsloan-dotfiles/blob/master/env/src/Process.hs#L165-L204)). The original code is safer, but I tried to simplify it at the cost of said safety. With that out of the way, let's start: the `getParentProcessID` you mentioned uses a primitive call, so it won't really help us. We'd need to work with what the operating system (in this case, Linux) provides us with.

I'll take PID `54742` as my working example. If I execute `cat /proc/54742/stat`, I'll be greeted with a bunch of numbers:

```
54742 (xmobar) S 1448 54742 54742 0 -1 1077936128 5426 2478991 0 0 20286 11071 4413 922 20 0 45 0 261768 1102823616512 11314 18446744073709551615 4194304 26203544 140728670498336 0 0 0 0 0 547334 0 0 0 17 11 0 0 3 0 0 26210368 28767304 33419264 140728670505038 140728670505049 140728670505049 140728670506968 0
```

it happens that the fourth entry is the PID of the parent process, in our case: `1448`. With that, we can write a function that fetches that entry for us

```hs
import           Control.Exception
import           System.Posix.Types


getParentPid :: ProcessID -> IO (Maybe ProcessID)
getParentPid pid = do
  let fp = "/proc/" ++ show (toInteger pid) ++ "/stat"
  econtents <- try $ readFile fp :: IO (Either SomeException String)
  case econtents of
    Right xs ->
      case lines xs of
        [ws] -> case words ws of
          (_:_:_:ppid:_) -> return . Just . read $ ppid
    _ -> return Nothing
```

*phew*, that was some work, but nothing complicated: generate the name of the file, read it, get the fourth entry, cast it to a `ProcessID`, and wrap it up in `Just`. If anything fails, return `Nothing`.

With that, we can go ahead and implement our `getParentsPids` function, which keeps reading PIDs until it hits `Nothing`:

```hs
getParentsPids :: ProcessID  -> IO [ProcessID]
getParentsPids pid = do
  ppid <- getParentPid pid
  case ppid of
    Just ppid' -> do
      ps <- getParentsPids ppid'
      return (ppid':ps)
    Nothing -> return []
```

And we're pretty much done. A little driver main:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  pid <- read <$> getLine
  getParentsPids pid >>= print . show
```

which prints `[1448,1,0]` when I give it `54742`. Seems right!

*Bonus*: we can make the code of `getPraentPid` a bit prettier by using `ViewPatterns`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import           Control.Exception
import           System.Posix.Types


getParentPid :: ProcessID -> IO (Maybe ProcessID)
getParentPid pid = do
  let fp = "/proc/" ++ show (toInteger pid) ++ "/stat"
  econtents <- try $ readFile fp :: IO (Either SomeException String)
  case econtents of
    Right (lines -> [words -> (_:_:_: (read -> ppid):_)]) -> return (Just ppid)
    _ -> return Nothing
```

*Bonus #2*: I would also rewrite `getParentsPids` more compactly with `LambdaCase`:

```hs
getParentsPids :: ProcessID -> IO [ProcessID]
getParentsPids pid = getParentPid pid >>= \case
  Just ppid -> (ppid :) <$> getParentsPids ppid
  Nothing   -> return []
```

Comment: Incredible answer.

Comment: It isn't safe to use `words` for parsing `/proc/*/stat`, the process name in parentheses may actually contain spaces (and unfortunately also parentheses). Try `cp /bin/sh /tmp/"oh shit) D 2 "`, run that and look at `/proc/*/stat`… It's probably necessary to search for the _last_ closing paren.